# Use given identity to computer exponent of 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I've been given an identity (that I don't know how to prove unfortunately), and been asked to use it to compute exp$(xM)$, where $$ M =
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           \\
       1 & 1       &1    & 1 \\
       1      &1     & 1 & 1 \\
1      &1     & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
The identity is exp$(M) = I_n + P(QP)^{-1}($exp$(QP) - I_k)Q$.

$M$ is $n \times n$, $P$ is $n \times k$, $Q$ is $k \times n$. $M = PQ$.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: You can compute it directly without using that identity..

Comment: Try computing $M^n$. It gives a very nice formula.

Comment: $M = e e^T$.  $M^2 = e e^T e e ^T = n M$. Or choose some orthonormal basis so $M = e_1 e_1^T$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I have to explicitly use the identity unfortunately

Comment: Why is the matrix not square?

Comment: @WillJagy D'oh! Thanks, I've fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
       1          \\
       1  \\
       1    \\
1     
     \end{bmatrix},  Q = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           
       \end{bmatrix}
$$
using that the rank of $M$ is $1$, and filling in the identity to get

$$ exp(xM) = \dfrac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}
       3 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x}   & -1 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x}       \\
        -1 + e^{4x} & 3 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x}& -1 + e^{4x}  \\
        -1 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x} & 3 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x}    \\
 -1 + e^{4x}& -1 + e^{4x} & -1 + e^{4x} & 3 + e^{4x}
     \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: It is also not difficult to prove the formula when $P$ is a column vector and $Q$ a row vector. Then just name a real constant $t = Q P = Q \cdot P$ as vectors, and $(PQ)^2 = PQPQ = P(QP) Q = t PQ,$ next $(PQ)^3 = t^2 PQ,$ then $(PQ)^4 = t^3 PQ,$ and so on. Note that $(QP)^{-1}$ just becomes $\frac{1}{t}.$